# androidplot - custom labels on Y and X

Tags: android, androidplot

I am trying to customize a graph generated with androidplot but I'm stuck on these two issues:

X axis: I want to show only the first (origin) and last ticks using two strings (which I set up in a different class) as labels

Y axis: values are normalized so [0..1] but instead of the 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc I would like to show the un-normalized value for each drawn series. I'm thinking **setRangeBoundaries()** is the way to go but how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can customize frequency of domain labels (x-axis) by using Plot.setDomainStep(...).  For example, you can show a label only for the first and last values in the plot:

```
plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.SUBDIVIDE, 1);
```

Then, to customize the labels for your range (y-axis) you can use something like this:

```
plot.setRangeValueFormat(new NumberFormat() {
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(double value, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
                // value is your raw value.  just transform it into your desired display
                // format, append it to buffer and then return buffer.
            }

            // unused
            @Override
            public StringBuffer format(long value, StringBuffer buffer, FieldPosition field) {
                return null;
            }

            // unused
            @Override
            public Number parse(String string, ParsePosition position) {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

More detailed info can be found [here](http://androidplot.com/docs/using-axis-value-labels/).